# Page entries in 3-level page table

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory, page-tables

I found this question but I can't figure out how to solve it.

> You are designing the Memory Mangement Unit (MMU) for a new processor. The processor has a word
>   size of 64 bits and pointers are also 64 bits in size.
>   The following parts of the design have been decided already:
>   •
>    The MMU will support a page size of 32kB.
>   •
>    It will perform address translation using a 3-level hierarchical page table.
>   •
>    As with x86 machines, each individual table at any level of the page table occupies a single page
>   of physical memory.  Level 3 is the root table, and contains entries which hold the physical ad-
>   dresses of Level 2 tables.  Level 2 table entries similarly point to Level 1 tables, and Level 1 table
>   entries point to physical pages or frames.
>   •
>    All page table entries will be 64 bits in size.
>   •
>    The Physical Address Space is limited to 52 bits (4096 terabytes) in size, which should be enough
>   for the time being.
>   The rest of this question is about the consequences of these design decisions.
>   **Question:** How many entries are there in each individual page table page? Show your working.

After some reading I found out that given a page size `P=2^p` and a virtual address size `n`, we have a Virtual Page Offset (VPO) of `p` bits and the Virtual Page Number of `(n-p)` bits. With that, the number of PTEs in a 1-level page table is:

```
2^n / 2^p = 2^(n-p)
```

In a `k`-level page table I need to split the VPN into `k` different VPNs, which, from my understanding, are all of the same length `(n-p)/k`. This would mean that the amount of PTEs in each individual page table is `2^((n-p)/k)`.

Now, in my case, I have `P = 32kB = 2^15`. This gives me a 15-bit VPO. What I am missing is the virtual address size `n`.
I know that the word and pointer size is 64 bits.
Am I right to assume that the virtual address is 64 bits wide? In that case, I would get `49/3`-bit VPNs, but `49` is not divisible by `3`.

Comment: If you don't know about multilevel paging, research. Hasn't this been covered in the courses you're attending anyway? But first, **do some research**. If you struggle understanding something on that way, we might help you. All you say is you found something for one-level paging but not for multilevel paging. Then look up how that works!

Comment: I just spent a whole afternoon trying to understand by reading and researching online and by looking at my course material, and because I have other exams to prepare I decided to ask for help instead of losing another day or even more on one question. If you don't want to (or can't) help than don't answer or down-vote, at the end this website is done to ask for help.

Comment: Yeah. Read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, then ask. I've learned it the same way and reading on your own about topics gives you a way deeper understanding than just an answer on SO anyway. You don't even show the slightest approach! You just copy & pasted some assignment or whatever.

Comment: If a page table entry is 8 bytes (2^3) and a page is 32KB (2^15) then there are 32KB / 8B entries in a page = 2^12 = 4K.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question, yes we have 512 (2^9) page entries total (8 bytes is 64 bits which is (2^6)), but I have 3 page tables and I have to say for each table how many entries it has.